# Does any denomination commemorate the Weaning Ceremony of Infant Jesus?

Tags: life-of-jesus, tradition, judaism, non-denominational

We read in Gen 21:5-8:

> Abraham was a hundred years old when his son Isaac was born to him.   Now Sarah said, “God has brought laughter for me; everyone who hears will laugh with me.”   And she said, “Who would ever have said to Abraham that Sarah would nurse children? Yet I have borne him a son in his old age.” The child grew, and was weaned; and Abraham made a great feast on the day that Isaac was weaned.

If the ceremony of weaning was an integral  part of Jewish tradition, Jesus as a child   would also have become the center of such a ceremony in his name . My question therefore is: Is there any denomination that commemorates the Weaning Ceremony of Infant Jesus ?

Comment: Besides this one account in Jewish history *before the Law* was given, is there evidence that any other Jewish period considered that point a festal occasion?

Comment: Yes;  please visit https://www.ritualwell.org/ritual/weaning-ceremony

Comment: I meant in Scripture.

Comment: You can log on to Bible Gateway Keyword Search for  `wean' and find a number of references , for instance, 1 Sam 1:22, 1 Kings 11:20,  Isaiah 11;8,  Is 28:9, Hos 1:8 and Ps 131:2.

Comment: It's your responsibility to do basic research for the question. Don't tell us to search the bible for some term. Show us what research has shown you